# Unknown type name int32

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have following line of code in my project and I am getting error Unknown type name int32

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 1060
     int32_t   NPP_WriteReady(NPP instance, NPStream* stream);
 int32_t   NPP_Write(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, int32_t offset, int32_t len, void* buffer);
 #else
  int32   NPP_WriteReady(NPP instance, NPStream* stream); // getting error here
  int32   NPP_Write(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, int32 offset, int32 len, void* buffer);// getting error here
#endif
```

I am using Max 10.8,Xcode 4.6.2 SDK,Base SDK 10.7 and Apple llvm compiler.

It seems Apple has removed the type int32 on and onwards 10.6.I have put #define for it but its not working.Please help me on this.

Comment: why isn't is int32_t like the others above?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus That is for older version of Mac I guess.I am not sure about it as I have just started debugging it.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus Does Mac SDk support int32 in older version ?

Comment: You are probably lacking the older header or library that included the int32 type. In C99 int32_t was included for use. However the int type is present in every implementation of C so I wonder why you are not using that?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus I guess my system does not have older SDK.Thanks for you help. Please put it as answer I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was found by checking what types were available in which implementation of C.

`int32_t` is available in C99.
However `int32` was not. The problem was that the system did not include the older SDK that did include the header/library which contained this `int32` type.

The normal `int` type is always present in every implementation of C, so perhaps the use of this one will help later cases of backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

since 10.7 napi.h has changed a lot.earlier int32 has been supported but now they removed it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/general/macosxlionapidiffs/WebKit.html